# Trouble gettings CanvasJS to color just the coordinates in the tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

The tooltip text:

`10
Dataseries 1: 71
Dataseries 2: 77`

I'm trying to get the tooltip so the `Dataseries 1:` and `Dataseries 2:` remain their current color, and the `10`, `71`, and `77` are colored red. I have tried `toolTipContent: " x: <span style='\"'color: red;'\"'>{x}</span> y: {y} <br/> name: {name}, label:{label} ",` but it doesn't change anything. I'm sure its a stupid mistake on my part, but I'm new to using CanvasJS and haven't been able to get anything to work. (https://jsfiddle.net/lightmaster/8p3ygwf1/)

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  backgroundColor: "RGBA(37, 41, 45, 0.9)",
  animationEnabled: true,

  title: {
    text: " ",
    fontSize: 11,
    fontColor: ' #ccc',
    fontFamily: "arial",
  },

  toolTip: {
    fontStyle: "normal",
    cornerRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: "RGBA(37, 41, 45, 0.9)",
    toolTipContent: " x: {x} y: {y} <br/> name: {name}, label:{label} ",
    shared: true,
  },

  axisX: {
    gridColor: "RGBA(64, 65, 66, 0.8)",
    labelFontSize: 10,
    labelFontColor: ' #ccc',
    lineThickness: 1,
    gridThickness: 1,
    gridDashType: "dot",
    titleFontFamily: "arial",
    labelFontFamily: "arial",
    interval: "auto",
    intervalType: "hour",
    minimum: 0,
    crosshair: {
      enabled: true,
      snapToDataPoint: true,
      color: "#9aba2f",
      labelFontColor: "#ccc",
      labelFontSize: 14,
      labelBackgroundColor: "#FF8841",
    }
  },

  axisY: {
    title: "Temperature (°F) Recorded",
    titleFontColor: "#ccc",
    titleFontSize: 10,
    titleWrap: false,
    margin: 10,
    lineThickness: 1,
    gridThickness: 1,
    gridDashType: "dot",
    includeZero: false,
    gridColor: "RGBA(64, 65, 66, 0.8)",
    labelFontSize: 11,
    labelFontColor: ' #ccc',
    titleFontFamily: "arial",
    labelFontFamily: "arial",
    labelFormatter: function(e) {
      return e.value.toFixed(0) + " °F ";
    },
    crosshair: {
      enabled: true,
      snapToDataPoint: true,
      color: "#9aba2f",
      labelFontColor: "#fff",
      labelFontSize: 12,
      labelBackgroundColor: "#FF8841",
      valueFormatString: "#0.# °F",
    }
  },

  legend: {
    fontFamily: "arial",
    fontColor: "#ccc",

  },
  data: [
    {
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55 },
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14 }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "spline",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 77 },
        { x: 20, y: 53 },
        { x: 30, y: 58 },
        { x: 40, y: 61 },
        { x: 50, y: 99 },
        { x: 60, y: 60 },
        { x: 70, y: 20 },
        { x: 80, y: 31 },
        { x: 90, y: 26 }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<!-- Just so that JSFiddle's Result label doesn't overlap the Chart -->
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the chart level, instead of `toolTipContent` you need `content`. Your `toolTipContent` code is currently being ignored because that's the property used only at the data level. Here is how you can set a style directly, doing basically what you asked for:

```
toolTip: {
  fontStyle: "normal",
  cornerRadius: 14,
  backgroundColor: "RGBA(37, 41, 45, 0.9)",
  content: "<span style='\"'color: red;'\"'>{x}</span><br/> <span style='\"'color: {color};'\"'>{name}</span> <span style='\"'color: red;'\"'>{y}</span>",
  shared: true,
}
```

Because you are using `shared: true`, your `x` value will show up twice. If you don't want that, look into the [contentFormatter function for Shared toolTip](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/tool-tip/) section in the docs.

Comment: Yours did work, but like you said it added an extra `x`. I looked at the contentFormatter from the docs and modified their contentFormatter code so that it shows the information I want, but when I replace the `<strong>` code with the `<span>` code, it stops being bold but doesn't change colors: https://jsfiddle.net/lightmaster/8p3ygwf1/

Comment: Nevermind, all I had to do was change up the quotes some so there wasn't a need for escaped quotes:
`contentFormatter: function(e){
          var str = '<span style="color: red;">' + e.entries[0].dataPoint.x + '</span><br/>';
          for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
            var  temp = '<span style="color: ' + e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + ';">' + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + '</span> <span style="color: red;">'+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + '</span> <br/>' ; 
            str = str.concat(temp);
          }
          return (str);
        },`